# Accessing all values in SOAP envelope

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, soap

I have a SOAP response which looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  
    <s:Body> 
        <RegisterAccountResponse  xmlns="http://site.com/services/player"> 
            <RegisterAccountResult  xmlns:a="http://site.com/entities/player/account"  
                    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
                <Token  i:nil="true" xmlns="http://site.com/contracts/common"  xmlns:b="http://site.com/entities/communication"/> 
                <StatusCode  xmlns="http://site.com/contracts/common">UserAlreadyExists</StatusCode>
                <StatusMessage xmlns="http://site.com/contracts/common">
                    Customer with same name and  date of birth already registered
                </StatusMessage>
                <a:PlayerAccount  i:nil="true"/>
            </RegisterAccountResult>
        </RegisterAccountResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

which somehow manages to populate the following response class:

```
namespace Site.Messages.Player.Account
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://site.com/entities/player/account")]
    public class RegistrationResponse : ResponseBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the player account.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The player account.</value>
        [DataMember]
        public PlayerAccount PlayerAccount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Response base:

```
namespace Site.Messages.Common
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class for all Request / Response classes.
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://site.com/contracts/common")]
    public abstract class ResponseBase : RequestResponseBase
    {

    }
}
```

RequestResponseBase:

```
namespace Site.Messages.Common
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class for all Request / Response classes.
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://site.com/contracts/common")]
    public abstract class RequestResponseBase
    {
        public string StatusCode; //always null

        public string StatusMessage; //always null

        public Token Token;
    }
}
```

It seems the following lines are responsible for kicking off this process:

```
ActivatedClient<Contracts.Player.IAccount> client = null;

try
   {
       client = new Activator().ConnectPlayerServiceAccount();
       return client.Instance.RegisterAccount(request);
   }
   finally
   {
       if (client != null) client.Close();
   }
```

This time around `PlayerAccount` is null as the SOAP message specifies but usually there is a serialised object in there.

I have the following questions:

- How can I access the value of `StatusMessage` which is defined in the SOAP envelope? (I've added the property to the class with the same name but it is never populated)
- How is this class even getting populated? (internal workings, rules etc)

Any pointers much appreciated - but as you can tell I am new to SOAP and just trying to understand somebody elses code.

Comment: Is it so hard to format the SOAP message to make it readable?

Comment: Show also your `ResponseBase` class.

Comment: @Ladislav - Apologies - I've added the response based it's just an empty abstract class

Comment: So there are not defined properties like `StatusCode` or `StatusMessage` in class hierarchy? If you add them to `ResponseBase` will they be populated?

Comment: Yes there is in a class called token which is the base of the base containing `Status`, `Message` etc- however the details in there are never populated (token remains null).

Comment: Can we see the definition of RequestResponseBase?

Comment: Jon Skeet - Are you out there?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the message that arrives the token is i:nil = "true" which is why your token is null

The StatusMessage and Message are siblings of the token in the message not children of it. You need to add StatusMessage and Message to RequestResponseBase for them to be populated

Comment: Thanks however it doesn't seem to work - they are still always null.  I've updated my question.

Comment: You'll need to set the Order in the DataMember attribute as the DataContractSerializer will be expecting alphabetic ordering: StatusCode, StatusMessage, Token

Comment: I've just tried changing the order to no avail - I've updated the question

Comment: Do you have any more suggestions?  It's as if the data just isn't being serialized/deserialized.

Comment: I'll try do repro it today or tomorrow